# Disable secure forms form parameter?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a multi-page freeform pro form which breaks every time the user uses the back button to go back to a previous part (the dreaded  "action is invalid error").

I can only get it to work properly by disabling secure forms globally in the control panel - is there no way to disable it just for this one form through a parameter?
Using FFP v 4.1.3 on EE 2.7.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not - when Secure Forms is enabled, EE requires every `POST` to contain a valid `XID`. More and more I'm just disabling Secure Forms on any site which takes user submissions because it brings so many headaches.

Comment: Thanks Derek, thought as much - though I could swear freefrom had a secure="no" parameter :) Maybe I'm confusing this with another add-on.

Comment: Low Search used to have a `secure` parameter, but he removed it (I think because EE 2.7 disabled its ability to work).

Comment: That's the one I may have been thinking about, OK.

Comment: Derek is right about the secure="no" param. However, you could (manually) set the csrf_exempt column to 1 in the exp_actions table for the action in question, which should solve it, too.

Comment: Can confirm this little workaround works fine - thanks Low!