# Freeform sumit contact form : You are not authorized to perform this action

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms, ee

I have a website I am moving to a ubuntu server from a windows server for a client.

ee v2.7.1
freeform 3.1.5
matrix 2.5.8

I have the contact form that was working on the other server but on this server that is not live I get this error. The form renders fine but when you submit you get:

```
The form you submitted contained the following errors

    You are not authorized to perform this action

Return to Previous Page
```

I figure it could be a couple of things:
1) the site is not live and the old one is so this is just normal?
2) file permissions issue
3) user permission
4) scratching my head...

So any pointers on EE forms would be a help as I have not built one in about 4 years.

Comment: Do you have secure forms enabled? Check "Security and Session Preferences" and see if disabling this setting solves it. It's been known to cause issues - see http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/disable-secure-forms-form-parameter for an example.

Comment: Secure forms is a very necessary security measure to prevent cross site request forgeries and it is not recommended to disable it to solve this type of error as its usually another issue.

Comment: The secure option made it work, I think it might be failing as its on on the live domain to, just an IP from a test i did about 5 years ago. Will be live soon now it works and can test again

Answer (score 1):

This error is happening due to the changes in secure form handling introduced in EE 2.7.

Freeform 3.1.5 is not compatible with EE 2.6+ and is no longer being developed or updated. You will need to upgrade to Freeform 4.x.

Comment: Thanks @solspace I am right in thinking though, I will need to re do the templates with the move to 4.x?

Comment: There are a few changes to make, which are detailed here: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/upgrade_3.x-4.x/

Answer (score 0):

That's a generic error message.  It can be returned in a number of circumstances. EE purposely does not reveal what error you triggered so as not to aid evil-doers.

I've seen this error when:

- I've submitted the same data more than once.
- I've submitted the same form without reloading the page (form hash being reused).
- I've submitted a form a long time after the page has loaded (form hash has expired).

There are probably other operations that can trigger this error, many of them come down to the form hash. Can you inspect your source to see if there's a hash there as expected? Can you compare that value to those listed in the hash table?

Comment: I shall go search but where/what is the hash table? Is this a form of session for the form?